# Trying to pull parts of each item from a list into a new list

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension, delimiter

I have a long list (called "CurrentTitleAndCompany") that looks like this:

> ['V.P. of Human Resources at Arkansas Glass Container Corp Â· 2019 â€“ Present', 'Compensation Benefits Administrator at Confederated Tribes of Warm Springs, Oregon Â· 2018 â€“ Present', 'Vice President Employee Benefits at USI Insurance Services Â· 2020 â€“ Present', 'Benefits Team Sub-Lead at ASM Research Â· 2019 â€“ Present',]

I want to create a new list (called "CurrentTitle") that takes the parts from each item that come before "at".

This is what I wrote, but I'm getting a "list index out of range" error:

```
CurrentTitle = []

for element in CurrentTitleAndCompany:
    CurrentTitle.append(element.split("at",0)[1])
```

Comment: There seem to be some encoding errors in your question. The input list doesn't contain `at` at all.

Comment: `titles = ...` your long list of titles.  then `CurrentTitle = [title.split('at')[0] for title in titles]`

Comment: thank you!  LPR, your solution solved this

Answer (score 0):

My personal suggestion would be for you to create a class and separate the titles from the companies, such as the following:

```
class CurrentTitleAndCompany:
    CompanyPersonOne = "Apple"
    TitlePersonOne = "CEO"
    CompanyPersonTwo = "Microsoft"
    TitlePersonTwo = "Vice President"


print("Person One currently works at", CurrentTitleAndCompany.CompanyPersonOne, 
"and occupies the title of ",
      CurrentTitleAndCompany.TitlePersonOne)

print("Person Two currently works at", CurrentTitleAndCompany.CompanyPersonTwo, 
"and occupies the title of ",
      CurrentTitleAndCompany.TitlePersonTwo)
```

If you need any other sort of clarification, hit me up!